Create Charts with AS_XLSX in Oracle APEX
I am using a version of Anton Scheffer's package As_XLSX to export data into reports from my application. I have tried to expand the capability to generate charts automatically from the data I am loading into the sheets but have not had any success.
The code I have tried added to the package body is:
procedure add_chart(
p_sheet       pls_integer,
p_chart_type  varchar2,
p_top_left    varchar2,
p_bottom_right varchar2,
p_range       varchar2,
p_title       varchar2 := null,
p_legend      boolean := true
)
is
t_xml clob;
t_drawing_blob blob;  -- Temporary blob to store the drawing
t_sheet pls_integer := nvl(p_sheet, workbook.sheets.count);
begin
-- Initialize drawings if not already done
if workbook.sheets(t_sheet).drawings.count = 0 then
workbook.sheets(t_sheet).drawings(1).img_id := 1;
end if;
-- Initialize the temporary blob
dbms_lob.createtemporary(t_drawing_blob, true);

-- Generate the chart XML
t_xml := '<c:chartSpace xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart">';

-- Chart type definition
if p_chart_type = 'bar' then
    t_xml := t_xml || '<c:chart><c:plotArea><c:barChart>';
elsif p_chart_type = 'line' then
    t_xml := t_xml || '<c:chart><c:plotArea><c:lineChart>';
end if;

-- Define the data range for the chart
t_xml := t_xml || '<c:ser><c:val><c:numRef><c:f>' || p_range || '</c:f></c:numRef></c:val></c:ser>';

-- Add title if provided
if p_title is not null then
    t_xml := t_xml || '<c:title><c:tx><c:rich><a:p><a:r><a:t>' || p_title || '</a:t></a:r></a:p></c:rich></c:tx></c:title>';
end if;

-- Add legend if requested
if p_legend then
    t_xml := t_xml || '<c:legend><c:legendPos val="r"/></c:legend>';
end if;

-- Close chart tags
t_xml := t_xml || '</c:chart></c:plotArea></c:chartSpace>';

-- Insert the chart into the drawing blob using add1xml
add1xml(t_drawing_blob, 'xl/drawings/drawing' || t_sheet || '.xml', t_xml);

-- Add positioning for chart in the worksheet
t_xml := '<xdr:twoCellAnchor><xdr:from><xdr:col>' || alfan_col(col_alfan(substr(p_top_left, 1, 1))) || '</xdr:col><xdr:row>' || substr(p_top_left, 2) || '</xdr:row></xdr:from>';
t_xml := t_xml || '<xdr:to><xdr:col>' || alfan_col(col_alfan(substr(p_bottom_right, 1, 1))) || '</xdr:col><xdr:row>' || substr(p_bottom_right, 2) || '</xdr:row></xdr:to>';
t_xml := t_xml || '</xdr:twoCellAnchor>';

-- Add the positioning data to the drawing XML
add1xml(t_drawing_blob, 'xl/drawings/drawing' || t_sheet || '.xml', t_xml);

-- Assign the temporary blob to the workbook's drawings
workbook.sheets(t_sheet).drawings := t_drawing_blob;

end;
For the body specification I added:
procedure add_chart(
p_sheet       pls_integer,         -- Sheet number
p_chart_type  varchar2,            -- Chart type (e.g., 'bar', 'line', etc.)
p_top_left    varchar2,            -- Top left cell for chart placement (e.g., 'A1')
p_bottom_right varchar2,           -- Bottom right cell for chart size (e.g., 'E10')
p_range       varchar2,            -- Range of data for the chart (e.g., 'A1:B10')
p_title       varchar2 := null,    -- Optional chart title
p_legend      boolean := true      -- Whether to include a legend
);
When I run this in my application I get an error stating no data is found, even after confirming I have added data to the cells I am referencing. Help!
